# Nested FOREACH in Neo4J Cypher runs infinite

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I try to run the following query, where I have 10 chains in database and 10 Countries. and using the array of 20 addresses.
Then I loop through those to create a store for each combination of country, chain and address, expecting 10*10*20 combinations - 2000 stores.
But instead, query runs until around 200 000 records are created and then halts with unknown error.

```
MATCH (Chains:Chain), (Countries:Country)
WITH Collect(Chains) as ch, 
     Collect(Countries) as cou, 
['Ullevål','Blindern','Centrum','Kringså','Lysaker','Skøyen','Fornebu','Stortinget','Nationalteatre','KarlJohan',
'Gamle','Grunerløkka','Grønland','Majorstuen','Snarøya','Asker','Sandvika','Drammen','Gothenburg','Stockholm'] as addresses

FOREACH(country in cou |
    FOREACH (c in ch |
            FOREACH (a in addresses |
                CREATE (s:Store {name:c.name+"_"+a, address:a})
                CREATE (s-[:BELONGS_TO]->c)
                CREATE (s-[:IN]->country)               )))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the following data...

```
FOREACH (i IN RANGE(1, 10) | 
    CREATE (:Chain {name:'Chain' + i}), 
           (:Country {name:'Country' + i})
)
```

...the first part of your query

```
MATCH (Chains:Chain), (Countries:Country)
WITH COLLECT(Chains) AS ch, COLLECT(Countries) AS cou
```

will result in length-100 collections for both `ch` and `cou`, since the `MATCH` is retrieving a Cartesian product (10^2 = 100). So that is where your 200,000 records are coming from: 100 * 100 * 20. You can verify this with the following:

```
MATCH (Chains:Chain), (Countries:Country)
WITH COLLECT(Chains) AS ch, COLLECT(Countries) AS cou
RETURN LENGTH(ch), LENGTH(cou)
```

which will tell you that each collection is length-100:

```
LENGTH(ch)  LENGTH(cou)
100         100
```

You can fix this by using `COLLECT(DISTINCT thing)` in the first part of your query to collect only the unique things...

```
MATCH (Chains:Chain), (Countries:Country)
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT Chains) AS ch, COLLECT(DISTINCT Countries) AS cou
RETURN LENGTH(ch), LENGTH(cou)
```

...which will tell you that `ch` and `cou` are length-10 collections:

```
LENGTH(ch)  LENGTH(cou)
10          10
```

Now your nested `FOREACH` will be creating 10 * 10 * 20 = 2000 records:

```
MATCH (Chains:Chain), (Countries:Country)
WITH Collect(DISTINCT Chains) as ch, 
     Collect(DISTINCT Countries) as cou, 
     ['Ullevål','Blindern','Centrum','Kringså','Lysaker','Skøyen','Fornebu','Stortinget','Nationalteatre','KarlJohan',
      'Gamle','Grunerløkka','Grønland','Majorstuen','Snarøya','Asker','Sandvika','Drammen','Gothenburg','Stockholm'] as addresses

FOREACH(country in cou |
    FOREACH (c in ch |
        FOREACH (a in addresses |
            CREATE (s:Store {name:c.name+"_"+a, address:a})
            CREATE (s-[:BELONGS_TO]->c)
            CREATE (s-[:IN]->country)               )))
```

"Added 2000 labels, created 2000 nodes, set 4000 properties, created 4000 relationships, returned 0 rows in 1262 ms."

Comment: Brilliant! It worked. Thank you a lot.
So, are you saying that MATCH (Chains:Chain), (Countries:Country) instead of matching individual nodes, will try to retrieve all pair combinations between them? Chains X Country? 
That's unexpected for me

Comment: @DavletD Yes. Compare this to SQL. If you select two columns from two tables without specifying anything else, you'll be doing a CROSS JOIN by default (which returns a Cartesian product). For example, `SELECT t1.thing, t2.otherthing FROM t1, t2;` will give you a Cartesian product because you haven't specified anything about how the rows should be joined. Similarly, in Cypher, `MATCH (t1:Table1), (t2:Table2) RETURN t1.thing, t2.otherthing` will return a Cartesian product. For both you would need to specify `WHERE t1.id = t2.id` or something similar to reduce the result set.